# Target specific Element UI notification

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I'm starting to use Element UI on a Vue app and can't see any obvious way to target a specific Notification instance.

As an example. I have a Vuex action that is triggering an info notification like so

```
Notification.info({
      duration: 0,
      title: 'Generating PDF',
      message: 'Please standby...',
      position: 'bottom-left'
    })
```

Once I get a response from the rest of the action, I then want to dismiss that particular notification and replace it with another, but the `options` for a notification doesn't have even as much as an id option to tap into.

I can't be alone in having the need to target a specific notification instance?

Comment: Info returns no reference?

Comment: I guess one approach would be to store the info object in another variable and  reassign it with your different options whenever you want to change the notification format.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of element ui:

> Notification and this.$notify returns the current Notification
>   instance. To manually close the instance, you can call close on it.

Or `Notification.closeAll` to close all notifications at once